# Is the p-adic Schwartz function uniform continuous?

Tags: number-theory, harmonic-analysis, automorphic-forms

In p-adic case, Schwart function is the function which has compact support and locally constant. But can we say its uniform continuity from this?

I think it would not be true, but I am not certain with great convince.

Would you let me know this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locally constant implies continuous, and continuous and compact support implies uniform continuity.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. It helped me very much.